# Scrape text from a complex DOM structure

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer, innertext

**Consider the following hierarchy in DOM**

```
<div class="bodyCells">
    <div style="foo">
       <div style="foo">
           <div style="foo1"> 'contains the list of text elements I want to scrape' </div>
           <div style="foo2"> 'contains the list of text elements I want to scrape' </div>
       </div>
       <div style="foo">
           <div style="foo3"> 'contains the list of text elements I want to scrape' </div>
           <div style="foo4"> 'contains the list of text elements I want to scrape' </div>
       </div>
```

By using **class name bodyCells**, I need to scrape out the data from **each of the divs one at a time** (i.e) Initially from 1st div, then from the next div and so on and store it in ***separate arrays.*** How can I possibly achieve this? **(using puppeteer)**

**NOTE:** I have tried using class name directly to achieve this but, it gives all the texts in a single array. I need to get data from each tag separately in different arrays.

***Expected output:***

```
array1=["text present within style="foo1" div tag"] 
array2=["text present within style="foo2" div tag"] 
array3=["text present within style="foo3" div tag"]
array4=["text present within style="foo4" div tag"]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your expected output is?  This would help the community in more fully understanding what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for updating?  So are the separate arrays themselves contained in a larger array?  Or is this just logged output?  Also, what would be the intended behavior if one of the divs contained an inner div?  For example: `<div style="foo3"> This is some <div>awesome</div> text!</div>`.

Comment: @AlexanderNied yes there's are 5 divs within it. it contains the text.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, you can fetch each of the texts in a single array using the class name.  Next, if you iterate over each of those, you can create a separate array for each subsection.

I created a fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/32bnoey6/ - with this example code:

```
const cells = document.getElementsByClassName('bodyCells');

const scrapedElements = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    const item = cells[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < item.children.length; j++) {
    const outerDiv = item.children[j];
    const innerDivs = outerDiv.children;
    for (var k = 0; k < innerDivs.length; k++) {
        const targetDiv = innerDivs[k];
      scrapedElements.push([targetDiv.innerHTML]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(scrapedElements);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. if there are some other divs within this, how do I achieve it?

Comment: You can use different css selectors to find the items within the page, or within a certain element you are looking for. I'd recommend reading up on using css selectors in javascript https://dev.to/neutrino2211/using-css-selectors-in-javascript-3hlm